# Объявление структуры в классе, в многофайловом проекте

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, struct

У меня есть изначально работающий код моего класса :

```
class Dictionary {
    struct node {
        map<string, string> data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* find(node* t, string search_word) {
       //код ф-ии
    }
}
```

Мне необходимо разделить реализацию и объявление через Header.h и Header.cpp. Как и где мне надо объявлять и описывать структуру node?
Если в .h пишу :

```
class Dictionary {
    struct node {
      //код структуры
    };
    node* root;
    node* find(node* t, string search_word);
}
```

А в .cpp :

```
Dictionary::find(node* t, string search_word)
{
  //код ф-ии
}
```

В cpp выдает ошибки : идентификатор "node" не определен. А так же ,что объявление несовместимо с .h

Comment: В `.cpp` фале возвращаемое значение функции отличается `int` <-> от декларации `Dictionary::node*`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe По хорошему, там должен быть не автоматический `int`, а сразу ошибка компиляции. Стандарт такого не разрешает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `.cpp`-файле нужно указывать возвращаемые типы функций. И именно в возвращаемых типах (и только в них, не в параметрах), вместо `node` надо писать `Dictionary::node`.

Так как возвращаемый тип пишется слева от имени класса, которому принадлежит метод, компилятор еще не знает, что `node` надо искать внутри `Dictionary`.

Альтернатива: использовать синтаксис trailing return type. Так как в этом случае возвращаемый тип справа от имени класса, там можно писать просто `node`.

Т.е. на выбор либо:

- `Dictionary::node* Dictionary::find(node* t, string search_word) {...}` - классический синтаксис
- `auto Dictionary::find(node* t, string search_word) -> node* {...}` - trailing return type

---

Также, возможно у вас получится спрятать и саму структуру `node` в `.cpp`-файл. Это возможно, если методы класса не принимают и не возвращают ее по значению, и она не хранится по значению в самом классе. (По указателю, как у вас в примере - можно.)

Для этого в хедере вместо нее надо оставить `struct node;` без тела, а в `.cpp` определить ее как `struct Dictionary::node {...};`.